# Hibernate slow insert-update many records

Tags: performance, hibernate, insert-update

I have a question about Hibernate. Should I put a lot of records in my database. In particular I have a list of objects, and for each of these I check if there is a DB, I make an update if there is otherwise save the new object. The problem is that even trying to batch insert entries are slow!
I am using spring+hibernate and mysql

table

```
create table `cash_outflow`(
 `cashoutflow_id` int(10) unsigned not null ,
 `year` varchar(4)  not null,
 `title_id` varchar(4) not null,
 `function_id` varchar(10)  default null,
 `service_id` varchar(10) default null,
  `operation_id` varchar(10) not null,
  `preventive` int(255) unsigned,
  `final_balance` int(255) unsigned,
   primary key(`cashoutflow_id`))engine = InnoDB;
```

Method for insert

```
public void insertCashOutflow(List<CashOutflow> result){
//  List<CashOutflow> resultUpdate = new ArrayList<CashOutflow>();
    List<CashOutflow> resultSave = new ArrayList<CashOutflow>();
    int newId=0;
    for(CashOutflow data: result){

        if(findByIntervento(data.getOperationId(),data.getYear())!=null){
            CashOutflow dataDB = findByIntervento(data.getOperationId(),data.getYear()); 
            if(data.getFinalBalance()!=0){
            dataDB.setFinalBalance(data.getFinalBalance());
            }
            if(data.getPreventive()!=0){
            dataDB.setPreventive(data.getPreventive());}
            getHibernateTemplate().update(dataDB);
        //  resultUpdate.add(dataDB);

        }else{

            resultSave.add(data);

        }

    }

    saveCashOutflow(resultSave);

}
```

Batch insert

```
    public void saveCashOutflow(List<CashOutflow> result){
    CashOutflow lastId = findLastId();
    int id=0;
    if(lastId==null){
        id=1;
    }else{
    id =lastId.getCashOutflowId()+1;}
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    int i=0;
    for(CashOutflow cash: result){
        cash.setCashOutflowId(id);
        session.save(cash);
        if( i % 100 == 0 ) { // Same as the JDBC batch size
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
        i++;
        id++;
    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

}


@Override
public CashOutflow findByIntervento(String operationId,String year) {
    List list = getHibernateTemplate().find("from CashOutflow where operationId=? and year=?",operationId,year);
    if(list.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }else{
    return (CashOutflow) list.get(0);
    }
}
```

Application context

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <!-- Crea automaticamente il database servendosi delle annotazioni nelle classi nel package domain  -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop> 
       </props>
    </property> 

    <!-- Indicates to Hibernate which package include the classes and the annotations for
            the mapping with db -->
     <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
        <!--    <value>it.uniroma2.model</value>    -->
            <value>it.uniroma2.dao</value> 
            <value>it.uniroma2.domain</value>
         </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- Bean to admin the transaction in Hibernate -->
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Tag to use @Transactional funzioni -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />de here
```

What can i do??Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for "findByIntervento()"?

Comment: There are two key performance items here: first is the bock for this loop "for(CashOutflow data: result)"; second is the method "saveCashOutflowI()". Can you check which is taking too long? Put some log in both to see long long it takes for each of these items.

Comment: Most of the time is spent to the loop. The loop takes more time than method "saveCashOutflow()"

Comment: Try set [`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html) property to 50 and check if there will some performance gain. You can change property value for fine tuning.

Comment: What's the average size of the loop "for(CashOutflow data: result)"? Do you perform this operation very often?

Comment: Result contains more or less than 2000 object. I call this operation not very often but i take 4 minutes to do this operation and i think that is too much!!

Comment: Are you running hibernate over a legacy database? Can you post CashOutflow class?